# Javascript push method to populate array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to display the `pushIssue` array on screen with  object `issue` pushed into array `pushIssue` with help of Javascript only. According to my knowledge it can be done with `pushIssue.push(issue)`, then I tried to display it on screen using `document.write()` but unable to display it

```
var issue = {
    id: 1,
    description: "This space is for description",
    severity: "This is severity",
    assignedTo: "Name of the assigned person",
    status: "Issue Status "
  }
var pushIssue = [];
```

Comment: Try `document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(pushIssue, null, 4) + "</pre>")`

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your time. It worked but I do not know how this code `JSON.stringify(issues, 0, 4)` works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pushing the element to the array, you could use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> The **`JSON.stringify()`** method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

for a stringified value in [JSON notation](http://json.org/) of the array.

```js
var issue = {
        id: 1,
        description: "This space is for description",
        severity: "This is severity",
        assignedTo: "Name of the assigned person",
        status: "Issue Status "
    },
    issues = [];

issues.push(issue);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(issues, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

For a better solution, because if the page is already rendered and while `document.write` generates a new page, you could use an `<pre>` tag and insert the stringified object.

```js
var issue = {
        id: 1,
        description: "This space is for description",
        severity: "This is severity",
        assignedTo: "Name of the assigned person",
        status: "Issue Status "
    },
    issues = [];

issues.push(issue);

document.getElementById('out').appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(issues, 0, 4)));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: This was the first thing I copied from your answers :-D

Comment: i know. that was the time without a console here.

Comment: Can I get a detailed explaination for this code `JSON.stringify(issues, 0, 4)` if possible with an example so that I can better understand it ?

Comment: please have a look to the linked documentation of `stringify`. basically it generates a string which looks like an object literal in javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Use pushIssue.toString() instead of only pushIssue.

Comment: The result will be exactly the same.